# conexão com banco de dados em java

Tags: java, netbeans

Bom eu fiz uma class para fazer a conexão com banco dedados:

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package semeq;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

/**
 *
 * @author SpiriT
 */
public class ConnectionFactory {

private static final String DRIVER = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
private static final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/helpsemeq";
private static final String USER = "root";
private static final String PASS = "";

public static Connection getConnection(){

    try {
        Class.forName(DRIVER);
        return DriverManager.getConnection(URL, USER, PASS);     

    } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
       throw new RuntimeException("Erro na conexão: ",ex);
    }
}

public static void closeConnection(Connection con){

        try {
            if(con != null){
            con.close();
        } 

        }catch (SQLException ex) {
             Logger.getLogger(ConnectionFactory.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }


public static void closeConnection(Connection con, PreparedStatement stmt){

    closeConnection(con);

        try {
            if(stmt != null){
            stmt.close();
        } 

        }catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ConnectionFactory.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

public static void closeConnection(Connection con, PreparedStatement stmt, ResultSet rs){

    closeConnection(con, stmt);

        try {
            if(rs != null){
            rs.close();
        } 

        }catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ConnectionFactory.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
}
```

e criei um jpanel no netbeans

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package semeq;

/**
 *
 * @author SpiriT
 */
public class NewJPanel extends javax.swing.JPanel {

    /**
     * Creates new form NewJPanel
     */
    public NewJPanel() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(this);
        this.setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 400, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGap(0, 300, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
    }// </editor-fold>                        


    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

mas esse j panel já herda o swing
como eu faria para chamar essa conexão com banco dedados para esse jpanel, para que eu possa exibir dados que estão no banco de dados?

Seria melhor utilizar por interface ou composição/agregração?

Sou novo no java.

Answer (score 0):

bom voce ja tem seu panel, agora basta saber o que voce quer retornar para seu panel..
por exemplo, o uso comum sao os DAOS, eles retornam algo relacionado a sua própria classe.

por exemplo>> Classe Cliente e Classe ClienteDAO.
a classe cliente tem seus atributos e a classe clienteDAO seria a responsavel por fazer o CRUD.

Já que estas usando o NetBeans recomendo usar o famoso "arrasta e solta" e montar sua JFrame e depois se preocupar em popular ela aprendendo mais sobre as classes DAO.